# ¿Cómo agregar información a un registro a través de su id?

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

Cómo puedo asignarle información a un registro por medio de su `id`?
Tengo una tabla en mysql llamada (clientes) con los campos:

(`id`,`nombre_cliente`, `direcc_cliente`, `telef_cliente`, `email_cliente`) los cuales son llenados a través de una ventana modal, y posteriormente muestro esos registros en una tabla
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ahora al hacer click en el botón (Agregar trabajo) sale la siguiente ventana modal
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que quiero hacer es que al abrir esa ventana me muestre el `id` del cliente del que seleccione en este caso fue el `id = 1` que corresponde al nombre de "Alonso" en un input y que esa caja de texto no la pueda modificar, esos campos son guardados en una tabla llamada (pedidos) con los siguientes campos:
(`id`, `Fecha_ingreso`, `NombreTrabajo`, `Cantidad` y `Anticipo`) y ya me los guarda. Pero ¿cómo puedo relacionarlos al `id` del nombre del cliente? para que al momento de hacer una consulta me salga el `id` del cliente y del trabajo que pidió?, y que al hacer click en otro registro en (Agregar Trabajo) no me salga la misma info que el `id` de otro cliente.

Les dejo mi código del modal Agregar Trabajo

```html
<form id="ingresarTrabajos">
  <div class="modal fade" id="dataTrabajos" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
      <div class="modal-content">
      
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
          <h4 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Agregar</h4>
        </div>
      
          <div class="modal-body">
          <div id="datos_ajax_trabajos"></div>


            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="Fecha_ingreso" class="control-label">Fecha de Ingreso</label>
              <div class='input-group date'>
                <input  name="Fecha_ingreso" type="text" id="datepicker" placeholder="Fecha" class="form-control" required="">
                <span class="input-group-addon">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                </span>
              </div>  
            </div>
        
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="NombreTrabajo" class="control-label">Tipo de trabajo</label>
              
                  <select class="form-control"  name="NombreTrabajo">
                      <option selected value="0"> Elige una opcion </option>
                      <optgroup label="Porcelana">
                        <option value="1">Corona metal porcelana</option>
                        <option value="2">Corona veneer</option>
                        <option value="3">Corona meriland</option>
                        <option value="4">Montado de porcelana</option>
                      </optgroup>
        
                      <optgroup label="Zirconia">
                        <option value="5">Corona</option>
                        <option value="6">Carilla/incrustacion</option>
                        <option value="7">Corona Monolitica</option>
                        <option value="8">Montado de zirconia</option>
                      </optgroup>
                  </select>    
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="Cantidad" class="control-label">Cantidad/Unidad:</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Cantidad" name="Cantidad" required="" placeholder="Cantidad">
            </div>


            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="Anticipo" class="control-label">Anticipo:</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Anticipo" name="Anticipo" required="" placeholder="Anticipo">
            </div>
          </div>
      
            <div class="modal-footer">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cerrar</button>
              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Guardar datos</button>
            </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

y mi código con el que mando los datos

```html
function load(page){
  var parametros = {"action":"ajax","page":page};
  $("#loader").fadeIn('slow');
  $.ajax({
   url:'ingresar_ajax.php',
   data: parametros,
    beforeSend: function(objeto){
   $("#loader").html("<img src='loader.gif'>");
   },
   success:function(data){
    $(".outer_div").html(data).fadeIn('slow');
    $("#loader").html("");
   }
  })
 }

 $( "#ingresarTrabajos" ).submit(function( event ) {
  var parametros = $(this).serialize();
    $.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     url: "ingresarTrabajos.php",
     data: parametros,
      beforeSend: function(objeto){
      $("#datos_ajax_trabajos").html("Mensaje: Cargando...");
       },
     success: function(datos){
     $("#datos_ajax_trabajos").html(datos);
     
     load(1);
      }
   });
    event.preventDefault();
  });

 $('#dataTrabajos').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
    var button = $(event.relatedTarget) // Botón que activó el modal
     var nombre_cliente = button.data('nombre_cliente')

    var modal = $(this)
    modal.find('.modal-title').text('Agregar trabajo a : '+nombre_cliente)
   
    modal.find('.modal-body #nombre_cliente').val(nombre_cliente)
    
    $('.alert').hide();//Oculto alert
  })
```

Comment: ¿tienes relacionada la tabla de "pedidos" con la tabla de "usuarios" mediante clave foránea?

Answer (score 1):

Problema:

> Los datos del modal son guardados en una tabla llamada `pedidos` con los siguientes campos: `(id, Fecha_ingreso, NombreTrabajo, Cantidad y Anticipo)`
>   ¿cómo puedo relacionarlos al id del nombre del cliente? para que al momento de hacer una consulta me salga el id del cliente y del trabajo que pidió?

Solución:

- Necesitarías agregar un campo mas a la tabla `pedidos`, para tener un `indice` que te permita indicar para que `cliente` es el `pedido`. Por ejemplo:

  ```
  ALTER TABLE `pedidos` ADD `idCliente` INT NOT NULL AFTER `id`, ADD INDEX (`idCliente`);
  ```
- Además podrías crear una `clave foránea` para enlazar ambas tablas y crear restricciones (o no), para mayor seguridad. Por ejemplo:

  ```
  ALTER TABLE `pedidos` ADD CONSTRAINT `pedidos_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`idCliente`) 
  REFERENCES `test`.`clientes`(`id`) ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE RESTRICT
  ```
- Es importante que a la hora de guardar/actualizar un `pedido`, ademas de los datos del `pedido`, envíes el `id` del `cliente`.
- Para obtener el `nombre del cliente` al momento de consultar los pedidos, podrías hacer lo siguiente:

  Supongamos que el `id` de pedido es `1`

  ```
  SELECT P.*,
    C.nombre_cliente
  FROM pedidos AS P
    LEFT JOIN clientes AS C
      ON C.id = P.idCliente
  WHERE P.id = 1
  ```

Lectura recomendada:

- [Integridad referencial en MySQL](http://programacion.net/articulo/integridad_referencial_en_mysql_263/4).